# Properties of the remainders from division into primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

This is a question that has bothered me for almost 6 years now on and off, and I still don't really know enough to tackle it.

To phrase it somewhat formally:

> Let $P$ be the series of prime numbers such that $P(i)$ is the i-th prime number.
>
> Let $N$ be a positive integer with a value greater than $2$.
>
> Let $X$ be the series of numbers such that $X(0) = 0$ and $X(i) = (X(i - 1) + P(i)) \pmod N$
>
> Does there exist an $N$ for which the set of elements $X(0),\ldots,X(N-1)$ contain every number from $0$ to $N-1$ exactly once? Can we prove it one way or another?

I've made computer simulations and let them run overnight and the results seem to suggest that no, there is no such N, but the graphs I got out of doing this are fairly interestingly shaped.

For instance, this is a scatter plot where the $x$-axis is $N$ and the $y$-axis is the percent of numbers in $X(0), \ldots, X(N-1)$ that were reached before a duplicate.
[image: Proportions]

And if we zoom in we can see some definite "structure" to the proportions, which is also interesting.
[image: Zoomed in]

And on the long tail there seems to be a definite "range", with some outliers

[image: Long tail]
I don't know how to explain why the graph is shaped like it is, or what the structure in it means, or why it seems like a "thick" logarithmic curve. The shape would seem to imply.

Also interestingly, the minimum proportion seems to approach ~0.0001592, which I have no clue the significance of.

Comment: Presumably the two curves correspond to some simple property of $N$ (for example, whether $N$ is even or odd)—you could look at the two sets of moduli to see.

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid. The top and bottom line have even and odd numbers.

Comment: I'm getting a very different-looking graph from yours. Can you give an example of the calculation of the $X$ series when $p=29$, say, and the corresponding point on the graph?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Here is the rust code I used to generate the data for the graph https://gist.github.com/bowbahdoe/c9bf4c5423943b5833ac8af85ef18913

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to interpret code to find the answer to my question....

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cVblq5js6MJfOM_KlfTxVkNFxowix2d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is the raw data as a csv file, if that helps at all. I don't have a straight formula for computing the series, but I could maybe walk you through the important bits of the code?

Comment: Also, looking into it more, the bottom line is even and odd Ns, the top line is only odd Ns

Comment: Your program is only testing each individual prime mod $N$ (main.rs, line 23), not accumulating the $X_i$ series as you describe, so I don't think your program is answering the question as stated. Bottom line is even $N$s and odd $N$s that are $2$ less than a prime; top line is other odd $N$s. This is easily explained, but it isn't the question asked, so I'll not explain here. Your question is still interesting.

Comment: You are entirely right and that explains alot - It wasn't even the graph i remember from a few years ago last time I did this. I'll update the question with the accurate graph

Comment: Let $s_n$ be sum of first $n$ primes.  Notice that if we can prove that for all $N\ge 10^4$,

$$\text{ There exist } j\lt k\lt N, \text{ such that } s_k\equiv s_j\pmod{N}$$

Then there are no solutions to your question. This holds for all prime numbers $N$ because $$s_i=s_{i-1}+p_i\equiv s_{i-1}\pmod{p_i}$$

So we have $i-1\lt i \lt p_i$ for any $i$th prime number $p_i=N$. I'm not sure how to prove this for arbitrary composite numbers though.

Comment: A solution for even $N$ (can be extended to odd $N$ if we have some good tight bounds on the sum of the first $n$ primes): We have $X(0) = 0$ is even and $X(1) = 2 (\mod N)$ is also even. 

If $N$ is even then since all other primes except $2$ are odd, we know $X(n)$ is even for all odd $n \geq 3$. Hence we have $X(0),X(1), X(3), X(5), X(7), \dots X(N-1)$ are even, so we are counting $\frac{N}{2}+1$ even numbers in the sequence $(X(n))_{n=0}^{N-1}$ and since there are $\frac{N}{2}$ even number in the sequence $0,1,2, \dots, N-1$ then by the pigeonhole principle we are done.